# Can't seem to resize image in Semantic UI Feed Summary

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, semantic-ui

I'm using the example code and trying to learn a bit more about Semantic UI. I like the Feed view, but I'd like to insert another avatar/mini image on the end of my summary line. I can get my other image in there, but I can't seem to resize this image like I can everywhere else via the classes (ui, image, mini). My original image is 200px x 200px

```
<div class="ui feed">
  <div class="event">
    <div class="label">
      <img src="/images/avatar/small/jenny.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="content">
      <div class="date">
        3 days ago
      </div>
      <div class="summary">
         You added <a>Jenny Hess</a> to your <a>coworker</a> group.
         <img src="/images/wireframe/image.png"> <!-- This is the problem image. Its 200x200 and I can't seem to resize it -->
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I'm using Vue, although I'm not sure that would matter. I've tried including a scoped style in my component like so:

```
.summary img { height: 35px; width: 35px; }
```

but that doesn't seem to matter. Nor does using the height/width attribute on the  itself.

Do I need to get more specific with my css?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to wrap your image in a flex box container and set max-width or max-height like this:

```css
 .summary {
   display: flex;
   flex-direction: row;
   justify-content: space-around;
 }
    
.avatar {
   display: flex;
   max-width: 32px;
   max-height: 32px;
 }
```

```html
   <div class="ui feed">
      <div class="event">
        <div class="label">
          <img src="/images/avatar/small/jenny.jpg">
        </div>
        <div class="content">
          <div class="date">
            3 days ago
          </div>
          <div class="summary">
              <div class="summary-text">
                You added <a>Jenny Hess</a> to your <a>coworker</a> group.
              </div>
             <div class="avatar">
               <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/200x200">
             </div>
              <!-- This is the problem image. Its 200x200 and I can't seem to resize it -->
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```